# How to add all cells in a column *in another sheet* before location of current cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ms Excel:

I have 2 sheets. Sheet1 ("RawData") and Sheet2 ("CumulData").

In Sheet2 I want the value of the cell to be the SUM of all cells in the same column before (and including) current location in Sheet1. So table in Sheet2 is basically an incremental count of data in Table in Sheet1.

```
Example:

RawData:
Level  Points
3       6 
1       1
6       9 
8       10

CumulData:
Level  Points
3       6 
4       7
10      16 
18      26
```

Thanks!

Comment: I came up with:

=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN(),1,,"RawData")&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())))

Does that make sens?

Answer (score 0):

in sheet Cumuldata:

```
B4=SUM(Rawdata!B$4:B4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its simple.
Just create a pivot table on the ColumnData sheet with Sum:)